# Aggregating after outer join using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge a large number of csv files with player names and results per year into one overview. I have a csv file per team with player names, birth dates and results per year. In some csv files, the birth date column is missing. I get duplicate rows when trying to merge files where the birthdate column is missing.

For example, for Team A in 2010, I have the following table of results, `teamA2010`:

```
    Player    Birthdate  2010
    John Doe  14-3-1999  12
    Jane Doe  15-6-1995  3
```

The result for the same team in 2011 is as below. Note the Birthdate column is missing. `teamA2011`

```
    Player    2011
    John Doe  2
    Jane Doe  1
    Alice     3
```

What I want is the following table:

```
    Player    Birthdate  2010 2011
    John Doe  14-3-1999  12   2
    Jane Doe  15-6-1995  3    1
    Alice                     3
```

I tried merging the table using an outer join (as new players may enter a team in later years), but am unsure how to aggregate over the birthdates and years?

```
    join_on = ["Player", "Birthdate"]
    if "Birthdate" in TeamA2011.columns:
       df = pd.merge(TeamA2010, TeamA2011, how='outer', on=join_on)
    else:
       join_on.remove("Birthdate")
       df = pd.merge(TeamA2010, TeamA2011, how='outer', on=join_on)
       join_on.insert(-1, "Birthdate")
```

The result is a table like below:

```
    Player    Birthdate  2010 2011
    John Doe  14-3-1999  12   
    John Doe                  2
    Jane Doe  15-6-1995  3    
    Jane Doe                  1
    Alice                     3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arised when I merged files with and without birthdays. Ultimately, I ended up merging all csv files and aggregating the results and birthdays at the end. Since birthdays might end up as duplicates or concatenated nan values, I had to replace these values.

```
df["Birthdate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Birthdate"])
df["Birthdate"] = df["Birthdate"].dt.strftime('%d %B %Y').astype(str)
group_by.remove("Birthdate")
df = df.groupby(group_by, as_index=False).agg(' '.join)

df["Birthdate"] = df["Birthdate"].str.replace(" nan", "")
df["Birthdate"] = df["Birthdate"].str.replace("nan ", "")
df["Birthdate"].loc[df["Birthdate"].str.count(" ") > 2] = df["Birthdate"].str[0:((df["Birthdate"].str.len()+1)/2).round()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to achieve this

```
  Player    Birthdate  2010 2011
    John Doe  14-3-1999  12   2
    Jane Doe  15-6-1995  3    1
    Alice                     3
```

I would do that:

`df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", on="Player")`
where
`df1 is the first df you provided` and `df2 is the 2nd one`

*EDIT*
You don't need to join on Bitrtday, even if there are multiple players with the same name and different BDay date. Outer join will take care of this.
The whole code:

```python
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["John Doe","14-3-1999","12"],
                ["John Doe", "1-1-1999"],
                ["Jane Doe","15-6-1995","3"]], columns=["Player","Birthday","2010"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["John Doe", "2"],["Jane Doe", "1"], ["Alice", "3"]], columns=["Player","2011"])


df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", on="Player")
print(df3)

Out:
     Player   Birthday  2010 2011
0  John Doe  14-3-1999    12    2
1  John Doe   1-1-1999  None    2
2  Jane Doe  15-6-1995     3    1
3     Alice        NaN   NaN    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Right outer join:

```
df = pd.merge(teamA2010, teamA2011, how="right", on="Player")
```

Output:

```
     Player   Birthday 2010 2011
0  John Doe  14-3-1999   12    2
1  Jane Doe  15-6-1995    3    1
2     Alice        NaN  NaN    3
```